# jquery get and set document offset (or position?)

Tags: jquery, offset

how is possible to get my actual document scroll and then set it after some event ?
I would like to get how my page is scrolled and after some event come back to this position.
thnk

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `$(window).scrollTop()` to get the current vertical scroll and set it with `$(window).scrollTop(value)` as well.

Comment: @Dee - please mark this as the answer if it does exactly what you need. Just hit the "tick" button.